# Decompose a surface integral over a triangluar area

Tags: surface-integrals

I have a triangular area defined by $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3) $ (assume they are arranged in the anti-clockwise direction).

And I have a function $T(x, y)$ defined by:

$$T(x,y) = \begin{cases} T_0, &\text{ if }\, T_0 > r(x,y)\\
r(x,y), &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$

Here $r(x, y)$ is a planar function, i.e., $r(x, y) = ax + by + c$ and $T_0$ is a constant.

Now I want to decompose the surface integral of $T(x, y)$ over the triangular area into some combinations of its line integral on three edges.

How I solve this problem in an analytical way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.